# error while load machine learning model in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning

I have create machine learning models in format .model. I need to load my machine learning models in order to get weight from models. But whenever I try to load the model it shows error:

```
Pa1 instance has no attribute 'load'`
```

It happens to all my models (Pa1, Ogd, Arow)

This is part of my program:

```
global clfs

clfs = [Pa1(), Ogd(), Arow()] #this is my model pool
print 'model pool size: ', len(clfs)
filedir = '/home/myfile'

for i in xrange(len(clfs)): # for each model in the model pool

    clfs[i].load( filedir + '_' + str(i) + '.model')
    
    # get original model weight
    w = clfs[i].coef_[1:]
    weights = []
    weight = [] # [i][j]: i = model index, j = feature index
    for w_num in xrange(len(w)):
        weight.append(w[w_num])
    weights.append(weight)
```

The way i save model:

```
for i in xrange(len(clfs)): # i = every model in model pool
        print clfs[i]
        print 'training'
        train_accuracy=clfs[i].fit(X_train,Y_train)
        ori_train_acc.append(train_accuracy)
        clfs[i].save( filedir + '_' + str(i) + '.model')
```

This is my myfile_1.model (only part of it because its too long)

```
model info:
{
    "clf_num" : 1,
    "cls_num" : 2,
    "loss" : "hinge",
    "model" : "pa1",
    "norm" : 0,
    "online" : 
    {
        "C" : 1,
        "bias_eta" : 0,
        "dim" : 36599,
        "lazy_update" : "false",
        "t" : 200
    }
}
model parameters:
weight[0]:
[ 0 -0.219641 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.0523282 -0.0452756 -0.0523282 -0.0043332 -0.000975608 9.32486e-05 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.00150336 -0.0131961 -0.00150336 -9.93554e-05 -0.0160645 -0.00972448 -0.00161313 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.0116229 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.0337869 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.00150336 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.00618885 -0.0265526 -0.0265526 0.0138585 -0.00191089 0.00196821 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 0.00223302 -0.0121794 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.0195 -0.00972448 -0.00180573 -0.00108076 -0.000975608 -0.000975608 -0.000975608]
```

I'm using python 2.7. Is there any solution to this? should i change the way i save model?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `model.save('path/to/location')` to save your model in `.h5` or  `.keras` format and load this model by using `keras.models.load_model('path/to/location')`. You can also extract the layers/weights of your model by using `model.get_layer()`